# How Display Custom Block Programmatically

Tags: block, drupal-modules, multisite

I have multi site drupal configuration and the database is different for each site and code base is same. I want to display a custom block created in all the multi site inside a custom module template page.

Block id is different for all the sites . so I can't load using block id  and since it is a custom block machine name also is not displaying.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 7, using [hook_block_info()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21block%21block.api.php/function/hook_block_info/7.x) implementation the custom blocks can be enabled in desired region.

In the documentation, look for `status`, `region`, `visibility` and `pages` keys specifically.

You can also alter visibility of the other blocks created by different modules (or core) by implementing [hook_block_info_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21block%21block.api.php/function/hook_block_info_alter/7.x) in your custom module.